# How to stop inline HTML comments from going to the next line when using Reformat Code in PHPStorm?

Tags: html, ide, phpstorm, webstorm

I am using PHPStorm IDE and in the meanwhile I also use HTML comments for the ending tags.
I use Reformat Code by `cmd+alt+L` keys a lot. I am aware that the Code Style in Preference will change the code style when using Reformat Code. However, it seems that I cannot change the HTML comments which are in the same line as HTML ending tags from going to the next line when I use Reformat Code feature which is annoying.
How can I change that to have the HTML comments inline with HTML ending tags when using Reformat Code feature?

[image: Inline HTML ending tag with comment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no such option.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-5070 -- star/vote/comment to get notified on progress.